# Etoken based application monitoring is not working in Windows7. What to do?

Tags: performance-testing

Hope you are all good.

We are in need of your help.

We are working on Etoken based performance monitoring.

Currently we are able to get monitors for EToken based applicaiotn from **XP** machines.

We followed the same procedure for Windows7, but we are unable to get performance monitors in **BAC** for the same.

The below error in **BAC** gives us big trouble to proceed further:[image]

We struck up with this. Any suggestions or solutions will be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day.